# Problems with php file uploading

Tags: php

I'm getting a really annoying problem with php file uploading. The albumcover file is optional, so I'have performed a control to check if the status is 4. The problem is that if I try to upload up to 5 songs, the script works perfectly, when I try with 6, 7, or more, the result is this die message:

"Formato file non permesso, sono ammessi solo files con estensione .jpeg o .jpg o .png"

But if the albumcover has not been uploaded the script should not enter into the true part of the if body. I don't know what the problem can be. This is my script:

```
<?php
session_start();

$nv = array("'","--");

$email = $_SESSION['email'];
$nomealbum = str_replace ($nv, '', $_POST['albumname']);
$desc = str_replace ($nv, '', $_POST['albumdescription']);
$genere = $_POST['genere'];
$singolo = $_POST['single'];

$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root', '') 
    or die("Cannot connect to the dbms");

$q1 = mysqli_query($conn, "use my_alessiocorvagliatsn") 
    or die ("Cannot choose the tsn_db");

if($_FILES['albumcover']['error'] != '4'){
    if($_FILES['albumcover']['error'] == 0){

    if($_FILES['albumcover']['type'] != "image/jpeg" || $_FILES['albumcover']['type'] != "image/png")
        die ("Formato file non permesso, sono ammessi solo files con estensione .jpeg o .jpg o .png");

    if($_FILES['albumcover']['size'] > 2097152)
        die ("Le dimensioni del tuo file superano i 2 MB");

    $img = $_FILES['albumcover']['tmp_name'];

    $prop = getimagesize($img);

    $larghezza = $prop[0];
    $altezza = $prop[1];

    if (($larghezza > 1600) || ($altezza > 1600) || ($larghezza != $altezza))
        die ("Le dimensioni del tuo file non sono consentite, caricare un immagine quadrata di massimo 1600x1600 pixel");

    for ($x=1; $x<=60; $x++){
        if ($x % 2){
            $str = $str . chr(rand(97,122));
        }
        else{
            $str = $str . rand(0,9);
        }
    }

    copy($_FILES['albumcover']['tmp_name'], "../imgalbum/".$str.$_FILES['albumcover']['name'])
        or die ("Impossibile trasferire il file immagine");

    $link = "../imgalbum/".$str.$_FILES['albumcover']['name'];
    }
}
else{
    $link = "../imgalbum/emptycover.png";
}

$q2 = mysqli_query($conn, "insert into tsn_albums 
(albumtitle, albumdescription, coverimglink, publishingdate, single, email) values
('$nomealbum', '$desc', '$link', now(), '$singolo', '$email')")
    or die ("Impossibile caricare album");

$q3 = mysqli_query($conn, "Select albumid from tsn_albums where publishingdate = CURDATE() and email = '$email'");
$a1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q3);
$albumid = $a1['albumid'];

if($singolo == 1){
    $nome = str_replace ($nv, '', $_POST['singolonome']);
    if($_FILES['singolocanzone']['error'] == 0){

        if($_FILES['singolocanzone']['type'] != "audio/mp3")
            die ("Formato file non permesso, sono ammessi solo files con estensione .mp3");

        if($_FILES['singolocanzone']['size'] > 10485760)
            die ("Le dimensioni del tuo file superano i 10 MB");

        for ($x=1; $x<=60; $x++){
            if ($x % 2){
                $str1 = $str1 . chr(rand(97,122));
            }
            else{
                $str1 = $str1 . rand(0,9);
            }
        }

        copy($_FILES['singolocanzone']['tmp_name'], "../songs/".$str1.$_FILES['singolocanzone']['name'])
            or die ("Impossibile trasferire il file audio");

         $linktra = "../songs/".$str1.$_FILES['singolocanzone']['name'];

         $q4 = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO tsn_tracks 
                (tracktitle, reproductions, genre, tracklink, albumid) values
                ('$nome', 0, '$genere', '$linktra', '$albumid')")
                or die("Impossibile caricare il singolo");

         echo "<i style='font-size: 12rem; margin-left: 44%; margin-top: 5%;' class='large material-icons'>done</i>
            <h3 style='text-align: center; margin-top: 5%'>Pubblicazione del singolo effettuata correttamente!</h3>";
    }
}

if($singolo == 0){
    for($z=0; $z<30; $z++){
        if(isset($_POST[$z]) && $_FILES['canzoni']['error'][$z] == '0'){
            $traccia = $_POST[$z];
            if($_FILES['canzoni']['error'][$z] == 0){

                if($_FILES['canzoni']['type'][$z] != "audio/mp3")
                    die ("Formato file non permesso, sono ammessi solo files con estensione .mp3");

                if($_FILES['canzoni']['size'][$z] > 10485760)
                    die ("Le dimensioni del tuo file superano i 10 MB");

                for ($x=1; $x<=60; $x++){
                    if ($x % 2){
                        $str2 = $str2 . chr(rand(97,122));
                    }
                    else{
                        $str2 = $str2 . rand(0,9);
                    }
                }

                copy($_FILES['canzoni']['tmp_name'][$z], "../songs/".$str2.$_FILES['canzoni']['name'][$z])
                    or die ("Impossibile trasferire il file audio");

                $linktraccia = "../songs/".$str2.$_FILES['canzoni']['name'][$z];

                $str2 = "";

                $q5 = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO tsn_tracks 
                    (tracktitle, reproductions, genre, tracklink, albumid) values
                    ('$traccia', 0, '$genere', '$linktraccia', '$albumid')")
                     or die("Impossibile caricare la traccia dell'album");
            }
        }
    }
    echo "<i style='font-size: 12rem; margin-left: 44%; margin-top: 5%;' class='large material-icons'>done</i>
    <h3 style='text-align: center; margin-top: 5%'>Pubblicazione dell'album effettuata correttamente!</h3>";
}  
?>
```

This is my form: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6t_u06RYI66Q2xrcTUxbC1sM3c

Comment: Show us what the form you're using to upload the files looks like.

Comment: And go read up on how to _properly_ prevent SQL injection. That str_replace stuff you got going on there is utter nonsense in that regard.

Comment: I see you adding a couple of input fields into a table in a loop - and then completely independent of that a form with only two input fields. Since the form is not close, we could assume that you might be outputting that table afterwards ... but that still doesn't allow us to tell if you messed that up somehow, created invalid HTML or whatnot. And I don't see a form field named `albumcover` anywhere. How hard can it be to show code that makes the problem actually reproducible ...?

Comment: And now you just removed the form code again ... are you kidding? Sorry, I'm out.

Comment: Sorry, i was trying to edit my post with my smartphone but i saw that the posted code was incomplete. Now I have updated the post with the right code. Sorry for that @CBroe

Comment: Relevant code belongs directly into the question, not on external sites. Would you mind reading [ask] first ...?

Comment: if( !in_array( $_FILES['albumcover']['type'], array( 'image/jpeg', 'image/png' ) ) )
        die ("Formato file non permesso, sono ammessi solo files con estensione .jpeg o .jpg o .png");

Comment: There was code not properly formatted, so I decided to attach a file in order to be more quick. Anyway I think that is not important how you can see the code, just see it, this is what matters.  @CBroe

Comment: Note that if you submit more than one file you should use something like: $_FILES['albumcover']['error']['file1']. So $_FILES['albumcover']['error'] is not 4, but an array of error codes.

Answer (score 0):

Since $_FILES['albumcover']['error'] is undefined (check your logs), it will be a false in [loose comparisons](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php). 
So false is not '4' and then false equals to 0. That is why you are reaching the die.

Try with strict comparisons:

```
if($_FILES['albumcover']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE){
    if($_FILES['albumcover']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK){
```